# Is it recommended to clear your flashdrive after successfully installing linux?

Tags: linux

I used my flashdrive as my bootable disk, and I’m curious as to whether I will ever need it since I’ve fully installed Linux.

Comment: You won't have your system partition resize itself live. But if you had to resize your system partition, you might be able to while booted from a flash drive.

Comment: [This link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) may help you find good tools both to make a USB boot drive and to restore it into a standard storage device.

Comment: It is a good idea to have a working USB boot drive with Linux (for example if you need to boot from it in order to repair your installed system or if you want to try Linux in another computer). But for me a USB flash drive is a temporary device, and as long as you have a working computer it is easy to make the USB flash drive bootable again with the same or a new version of Linux.

Comment: @sudodus Thank you, I didn’t find it too difficult to make a flash drive bootabe, but I have another extra so it wouldn’t hurt to keep this one as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons why you might need a Linux boot drive in the future. Personally, I have one on my keychain at all times.

The two main reasons (at least for me) are:

1. If you break something on your installation and need to fix it.
2. Doing operations on an OS that are not possible while it is running.

Number 1 is self explanatory. As for number 2, I have found myself trying to either delete or move files on a Windows installation, but for some reason it doesn't allow the action. If you decide that you know what you're doing, you should be able to mount the partition from a Linux boot drive and manually perform the action. This has helped me several times in the past. Additionally, if you need to backup your root partition, you should do so when it is not in use (i.e. when the OS isn't running).

If you have a second computer that you know you'll be able to use to easily burn a Linux install image, it isn't necessary to always keep it on a flash drive. But if  you find it annoying/difficult to burn an image, it can be convenient to have a flash drive with one on hand.

Comment: Linux is my sole OS, so I won’t be doing any windows installation, but I don’t have a good reason to clear my drive, and you guys gave me good enough reasons to keep it. So I’ll just use my extra flash drive for storage.

Answer (score 1):

You should be "ready" to boot without your disk (without root, kernel and grub), and for that a bootable flash drive is first choice. Ideally to fix a simple but fatal misconfiguration, otherwise to save the files from a dying disk.

But you don't even have to use the original - any minimal linux system will do. And you don't have to have it ready in seconds, probably. If your only system gets unbootable, you'd have to ask your neighbour to download the boot image for you --- worst scenario. No wait, that would be if you don't even have a flash drive...

If you wish to keep one or more installation images (for eternity or in a offline collection) you could save the (downloaded) image as a normal file, on disk or on a big flash. That way, a flash drive can hold more than one image.

Then you still might need your neighbour (or a second linux system) to issue the `dd ...` command, but you don't need the internet to emergency-boot your system.

A good test would be if you boot with your flash drive and see if you can mount one of your partitions and list and edit a file, and copy files to another drive...